# Order function in R: argument lengths differ

Tags: r, arguments

I'm getting the following error in R:

```
argument lengths differ.
```

I have a data set I would like to order on two columns, first on caseID, then on a column that contains a timestamp. I use the following code:

```
mydata <- mydata[order(mydata[ ,col1], mydata[ ,col2], decreasing = FALSE),]
```

Col1 and col2 are two variables holding an integer. I have looked at similar questions and tried the solutions that were proposed there, but nothing worked ;).

Could someone please help me?

Kind regards

Comment: please provide the output of `dput(head(mydata))`

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you are not quoting the column names.

Answer (score 9):

R thinks that you 2 columns have different lengths, sometimes that happens when you accidentally access a column that does not exist, check the values of `col1` and `col2` to make sure that they are appropriate numbers.  Also look at `length(mydata[,col1])` and `length(mydata[,col2])` to see if those 2 values match.  Also check for missing `,` or other punctuation, sometimes if you don't have the syntax exactly right then you get a list of length 1, or a single element vector which does not match the other vector in length.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same problem, but was able to get my code working. Try this code.

```
with(mydata, mydata[order(col1,col2),]).
```

The result is decreasing, so adding function decreasing = False was not necessary. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's nice to check this similar post out, uses dplyr package to solve it and it helped me: [Arrange within a group with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43832434/arrange-within-a-group-with-dplyr)

This might do the trick:

```
library(dplyr)
mydata <- mydata %>%
  arrange(
    col1,
    col2,
    desc(col3)
  )
```