# Order data frame by columns with different calling schemes

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

Say I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = c(2, 2, 2, 1),
                 x2 = c(3, 3, 2, 1),
                 let = c("B", "A", "A", "A"))
df
  x1 x2 let
1  2  3   B
2  2  3   A
3  2  2   A
4  1  1   A
```

If I want to order `df` by `x1`, then `x2` then `let`, I do this:

```
df2 <- df[with(df, order(x1, x2, let)), ]
df2
  x1 x2 let
4  1  1   A
3  2  2   A
2  2  3   A
1  2  3   B
```

However, `x1` and `x2` have actually been saved as an `id <- c("x1", "x2")` vector earlier in the code, which I use for other purposes.

So my problem is that **I want to reference `id` instead of `x1` and `x2`** in my `order` function, but unfortunately anything like `df[order(df[id], df$let), ]` will result in a `argument lengths differ` error.

From what I can tell (and this has been addressed at [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20805726/order-function-in-r-argument-lengths-differ)), the problem is that `length(df[id]) == 2` and `length(df$let) == 4`.

I have been able to make it through this workaround:

```
df3 <- df[order(df[, id[1]], df[, id[2]], df[, "let"]), ]
df3
  x1 x2 let
4  1  1   A
3  2  2   A
2  2  3   A
1  2  3   B
```

But it looks ugly and depends on knowing the size of `id`.

**Is there a more elegant solution to sorting my data frame by `id` then `let`?**

Comment: That works for `id`, but what about for `id` then `let` (I'll make the bottom of my post clearer)?

Comment: I'm still checking if it did the trick in my real case, but as far as the mock data goes, Works like a charm. Thanks a lot, Ananda, you're a job saver!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using `do.call(order, ...)` and combining `id` and "let" with `c()`:

```
id <- c("x1", "x2")

df[do.call(order, df[c(id, "let")]), ]
#   x1 x2 let
# 4  1  1   A
# 3  2  2   A
# 2  2  3   A
# 1  2  3   B
```